# In Quartz, how do I notify a job that the scheduler is shutting down?

Tags: scheduling, quartz.net, shutdown

I am using Quartz.Net to schedule some long running jobs in a Windows service.  I am trying to stop the service gracefully, such as when preparing to reboot. I need to notify the jobs so that they can decide whether to finish or abort based on how close they are to finishing.  I have looked at interruptions as well as listeners, but I can't seem to figure out how to communicate the pending shutdown.

I have also tried breaking the long jobs into smaller, sequential jobs, but there is a serious performance hit when I do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think a job instance can determine on its own that the scheduler is shutting down. Some coordination is needed between the job (worker) thread and the service control thread.

Here's an example interruptable job class. Note the use of `ManualResetEventSlim` to signal that an interruption has been requested, and to signal that the Execute() method has exited accordingly.

Note: this code is built on the Quartz.Server.2010 sample project code that ships with the source download.

```
/// <summary></summary>
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class DumbInterruptableJob : IInterruptableJob, IDisposable
{
    private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(DumbInterruptableJob));

    private ManualResetEventSlim _interruptRequestToken;
    private ManualResetEventSlim _interruptCompleteToken;

    /// <summary></summary>
    public DumbInterruptableJob()
    {
        _interruptRequestToken = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
        _interruptCompleteToken = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
    }

    /// <summary></summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            JobKey key = context.JobDetail.Key;

            logger.Info(m => m("Instance {0} of DumbInterruptableJob is working.", key));

            // The work loop
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if (_interruptRequestToken.IsSet)
                {
                    logger.Info(m => m("Work interrupt requested...Exiting."));  // Breakpoint #1
                    return;
                }

                logger.Info(m => m("Work..."));
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }

            logger.Info(m => m("Work complete!"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(m => m(ex.Message));
        }
        finally
        {
            _interruptCompleteToken.Set();
        }
    }

    /// <summary></summary>
    public void Interrupt()
    {
        logger.Info(m => m("Setting interrupt flag..."));
        _interruptRequestToken.Set();

        logger.Info(m => m("Waiting for work thread to stop..."));
        _interruptCompleteToken.Wait();
        logger.Info(m => m("Work thread stopped."));  // Breakpoint #2
    }

    /// <summary></summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _interruptCompleteToken.Dispose();
        _interruptRequestToken.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The next step is to interrupt (cancel) all running interruptable jobs when the service is stopping.

```
    public virtual void Stop()
    {
        try
        {
            // Calling Shutdown(false) stops the scheduler from starting new jobs,
            // but the method doesn't block, allowing us to access any running jobs
            // and attempt to cancel (interrupt) them.
            logger.Info(m => m("Shutting down the scheduler..."));
            scheduler.Shutdown(false);

            var interruptableJobs = new List<Task>();

            foreach (var ctx in scheduler.GetCurrentlyExecutingJobs())
            {
                if (ctx.JobInstance is IInterruptableJob)
                {
                    interruptableJobs.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        logger.Info(m => m("Waiting for interruptable job {0} to stop...", ctx.JobDetail.Key));
                        scheduler.Interrupt(ctx.JobDetail.Key);
                        logger.Info(m => m("Interruptable job {0} has stopped.", ctx.JobDetail.Key));
                    }));
                }
            }

            if (interruptableJobs.Count > 0)
            {
                logger.Info(m => m("Waiting for all interruptable jobs to stop..."));
                Task.WaitAll(interruptableJobs.ToArray());
                logger.Info(m => m("All interruptable jobs have stopped."));
            }

            logger.Info(m => m("Waiting for all running jobs to complete..."));
            scheduler.Shutdown(true);
            logger.Info(m => m("All running jobs have completed. Scheduler shutdown complete."));  // Breakpoint #3
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(string.Format("Scheduler stop failed: {0}", ex.Message), ex);
            throw;
        }

        logger.Info("Scheduler shutdown complete");
    }
```

To see the synchronization in action, set breakpoints where indicated in comments, run it, then shutdown the service (Ctrl-C if running from command line), and watch the order that the breakpoints are hit.

Answer (score 0):

You mention it, but have you tested if "void Interrupt()" is called when the Scheduler shuts down?

If that doesn't work, I think there isn't a built in way.

But if you want to explore all possibilities, get the source code for Quartz.Net, and instead of referencing a built library, add all the (quartz.net) .csproj's to your .sln and reference "by project"...and step through the code that way.  Or at least look at the source code to glean clues.

Then chase this

```
namespace Quartz.Core
{

    public class QuartzScheduler : MarshalByRefObject, IRemotableQuartzScheduler
    {
    {
        public virtual void Shutdown(bool waitForJobsToComplete)
        {
            if (shuttingDown || closed)
            {
                return;
            }
```

Here is a sample IInterruptableJob.  Worth a shot to see if the method fires or not.  You may have already tried this, but since you do not show the code for the job, this is a "what did someone else" do sample.

```
 public class AnInterruptableJob : IJob, IInterruptableJob
    {

        private bool _isInterrupted = false;

        private int MAXIMUM_JOB_RUN_SECONDS = 10;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Called by the <see cref="IScheduler" /> when a
        /// <see cref="ITrigger" /> fires that is associated with
        /// the <see cref="IJob" />.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {

            /* See http://aziegler71.wordpress.com/2012/04/25/quartz-net-example/ */

            JobKey key = context.JobDetail.Key;

            JobDataMap dataMap = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap;

            int timeOutSeconds = dataMap.GetInt("TimeOutSeconds");
            if (timeOutSeconds <= 0)
            {
                timeOutSeconds = MAXIMUM_JOB_RUN_SECONDS;
            }

            Timer t = new Timer(TimerCallback, context, timeOutSeconds * 1000, 0);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("AnInterruptableJob Start : JobKey='{0}', timeOutSeconds='{1}' at '{2}'", key, timeOutSeconds, DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()));

            try
            {
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7));
            }
            catch (ThreadInterruptedException)
            {
            }

            if (_isInterrupted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Interrupted.  Leaving Excecute Method.");
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("End AnInterruptableJob (should not see this) : JobKey='{0}', timeOutSeconds='{1}' at '{2}'", key, timeOutSeconds, DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()));

        }

        // Timer t = new Timer(TimerCallback, context, 1000, 0);
        private void TimerCallback(Object o)
        {
            IJobExecutionContext context = o as IJobExecutionContext;

            if (null != context)
            {
                context.Scheduler.Interrupt(context.FireInstanceId);
            }
        }

        public void Interrupt()
        {
            _isInterrupted = true;
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("AnInterruptableJob.Interrupt called at '{0}'", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()));
        }
    }
}
```